# Prevent tags being used in <td>

Tags: html, css, web

Users can send comments on my site and those comments are shown in table. The problem is, if user sends comment for example `<h1>Hello</h1>` the comment will show as

## Hello

instead of just `<h1>Hello</h1>` which it should. What is the possible solution?

Comment: What server-side are you using to handle this?

Comment: blacklist undesirable tags and strip them from the input, and/or HTML-encode your output back into the comments area would be the obvious options. You should be doing something along these lines anyway to prevent script injection attacks etc. Have you done any research or tried any techniques?

Comment: it's because you just let it parse the data as html by the browser. You need to encode it to show tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You Can Use The `htmlentities`**

```
<?php

  $comments = "A 'quote' is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;"; 
  echo "<textarea>".htmlentities($comments )."</textarea>";

 ?>
```

**DEMO::** http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/n0sf-b7ka

> **You Can Also Do This.**

```
  if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_POST["comments"])) {

       $comments = $_POST["comments"];

      echo "<textarea>".htmlentities( $comments )."</textarea>";

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP as server-side, you can use strip_tags() function to remove all the html tags from the comment text.
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strip_tags.asp

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the lack of detailed information, I can propose you this solution:

Transform all tags with String replacement as follows:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

should become

```
&lt;h1&gt;Hello&lt;/h1&gt;

i.e. '<' should be replaced with '&lt;', '>' with '&gt;'
```